# int([x[, base]]). Square brackets in functions in Python documentation?

Tags: python, function, brackets

What is the meaning of the square brackets inside the round brackets of a function in the Python documentation?

E.g.:

[**help**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help)(**[***object***]**)

or

[**int**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int)(**[***x***[**, *base***]]**)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Everything that is in square brackets is optional, i.e. you can omit it. If the square brackets contain more than 1 argument, you can't choose which ones to omit, you must either specify all of them, or none.
That's where nested brackets come in handy:

```
int([x[, base]])
```

Here, for example, you can use `int()` without arguments (by omitting the whole outer bracket) or `int(x)` (by omitting the inner bracket) or `int(x, base)`. But not `int(base)` (well, that would just mean `int(x)`).

This isn't actual Python syntax, just a way for documentation to be clearer. Python 3's documentation tries to avoid these brackets.

Comment: Python is different. It is possible to choose which optional argument you want to pass and omit the others. This is possible thanks to so called keyword arguments.

Comment: @Tadeck: I'm just talking about square brackets, not functions and arguments in general.

Answer (score 4):

These are optional arguments. You need not specify them, but you may want to use them for specific functionality.

> When one or more top-level parameters have the form parameter =
>   expression, the function is said to have “default parameter values.”
>   For a parameter with a default value, the corresponding argument may
>   be omitted from a call, in which case the parameter’s default value is
>   substituted. If a parameter has a default value, all following
>   parameters must also have a default value — this is a syntactic
>   restriction that is not expressed by the grammar.

[source](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)