# Parameters in PHP documentation, squared brackets?

Tags: php, function

This function for example...

```
int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

It takes the strings `$pattern` and `$subject`. However, what is `[`?

Comment: This is a documentation syntax - you don't actually put the square brackets into code.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053286/intx-base-square-brackets-in-functions-in-python-documentation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read API documentation for newbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is how the documentation for a function indicates arguments that are optional

Comment: can I for example skip the first optional argument (&$matches) but have the last two in this example?

Comment: @korayTugay unfortunatlely nope. You can check what the default value was and pass it though. Because the function figures out the parameter based on the index. If you're writing your own functions and want to have orderless optional parameters, you can pass an array

Comment: @KorayTugay — No. They are optional *within* the group of preceding arguments (hence the nested square brackets)

Comment: No as all three optional parameters are wrapped in the same square bracket.

Comment: @KorayTugay If this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old convention from Unix systems' [Usage messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message):

> On Unix-like platforms, usage messages tend to follow the same
> commonly-used pattern users are familiar with. They often begin with
> "Usage:" (hence possibly the name), the command, followed by a list of
> arguments. To indicate optional arguments, Square brackets are
> commonly used, and can also be used to group parameters that must be
> specified together. Exclusive parameters can be indicated by
> separating them with vertical bars within groups.
>
> Here is a thorough example based on the NetBSD source code style
> guide:
>
> Usage: program [-aDde] [-f | -g] [-n number] [-b b_arg | -c c_arg]
> req1 req2 [opt1 [opt2]]
>
> This would indicate that "program" should be called with:
>
> - options without operands: a, D, d, e (any of which may be omitted). Note that in this case some parameters are case-sensitive
> - exclusive options: f, g (denoted by the vertical bar)
> - options with operands: n
> - exclusive options with operands: b, c
> - required arguments: req1, req2
> - optional argument opt1, which may be used with or without opt2 (marked optional within the group by using another set of square brackets)
> - optional argument opt2, which requires opt1