# Why does the getopt method have getopt(args, options[, long_options]) not getopt(args, options,[ long_options]) as its signature?

Tags: python, getopt

I'm writing some code for a command line program and I'm using the `getopt()` function.
Can someone explain the options / long_options syntax?

```
getopt.getopt(args, options[, long_options])
```

My question is this:

Why does is the list fragmented between arguments? why is it options[ not options?

Comment: Please try and make your titles searchable. If you're querying something specific put it in the title "this function" doesn't help anyone find this question in the future.

Comment: are you asking why the square bracket includes the comma?!

Comment: No, why are the brackets being used that way? Why is this legal syntax to call this getopt(args, options[, long_options]) not options,[long_options].

Comment: Basically what is the significance of the square brackets here. This function looks as if the parameter names are args, options[, and long_options]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function has 2 required arguments (`args` and `options`) and one option that is not required (`long_options`).  The exact meaning of `args`, `options` and `long_options` can all be found in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt)

Basically, if you want the commandline to be parsed as:

```
myprogram --foo=bar
```

Then you need to have a `long_options` list which looks something like `['--foo=']`, but if you want to parse it as:

```
myprogram -f bar
```

then you would have `options` set to `'f:'`.  Of course, you can mix and match as much as you want.

For what its worth, I would never recommend anyone use `getopt` in favor of `optparse` or (even better) `argparse`.  These later two modules make working with `getopt` feel like trying to use a hammer to build yourself a new computer ...

Comment: I understad that part but what is the significance of the way the square brackets are being used? Just the syntax.

Comment: @Nirma -- The square brackets mean that the option is not required.

Comment: @Nirma -- The best I can do is [this](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#signatures).  sphinx is the tool used to generate the python docs.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using `argparse` instead of `getopt` which is now deprecated. About explanations, the documentation is really accessible:

- http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html
- http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

and about your specific question, I think you'd have your answer there:

- http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax

(read about [this](http://ttboj.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/getopt-vs-optparse-vs-argparse/) and [that](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/) to know why you should be using `argparse` ; even `getopt` documentation states (sic) "*Users who are unfamiliar with the C getopt() function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the argparse module instead.*")

*AFTER LAST EDIT*: when in a documentation you see a part of the prototype surrounded by square brackets, by convention, that means that part is optional, whereas the part that's before is mandatory. When you want to call `getopt.getopt()` you **shall** valuate `args` and options`.

Now, it is not `getopt.getopt(args, options, [long_options])` because it would mean the last comma would be mandatory too, though if you call `getopt.getopt(args, options,)` it is not a valid python expression.

*AFTER LAST COMMENT*: well, that syntax is a convention used across almost every tool existing on unix platform... I don't know if it has been defined somewhere, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was older than the POSIX specification itself! The only piece of "documentation" I could find is the following wikipedia page, but it lacks references:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message

I found a course at caltech (lookup section "*Optional arguments in usage statements*") that tells to use square brackets for optional arguments:

- http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/general/usage.html

And finally you're not the first asking this here on stack overflow, there are at least two other questions on the same subject:

- [int([x[, base]]). Square brackets in functions in Python documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053286/intx-base-square-brackets-in-functions-in-python-documentation)
- [What do square brackets, "[]", mean in function/class documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718903/what-do-square-brackets-mean-in-function-class-documentation)

If you look at manpages on your system, you'll see all of them using that syntax, all parameters in square brackets being **optional**, e.g.: [`ls` manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls), [`cat` manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat), even macos' [`open` manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) uses that convention!

I hope this time I did answer your question!

Comment: This does not answer my original question at all, Im asking about the syntax of that particular prototype and why its called options[ not options.

Comment: If you know where there is some python documentation explaining this syntax please link to it.

Comment: in that particular syntax, you're misreading it: the second argument is called `options` followed by `[, long_options])` the square brackets are only there to tell you that `long_options` is optional. What it means is that it can be either `getopt(args, options)` OR `getopt(args, options, long_options)`, depending on your needs!

Answer (score 0):

The arguments `args` and `options` are mandatory arguments, and long_options is optional argument to the function i.e. it may or may not be provided.
You will provide it in your command line utility if you intend to support long options like 
`--format` along with  `-f` .

Example of Linux `ls` utility, showing both options and long options, which start with `--`

```
LS(1)                                       User Commands                                       LS(1)

NAME
       ls - list directory contents

SYNOPSIS
       ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       List  information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).  Sort entries alphabeti‐
       cally if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort is specified.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

       -a, --all
              do not ignore entries starting with .

       -A, --almost-all
              do not list implied . and ..

       --author   <--- LONG OPTIONS OF COMMAND LINE
              with -l, print the author of each file
```